# Cleaning up when moving a stack/package to a different directory so rosmake won't complain

Tags: rosmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Background: I just had some difficulty rebuilding a stack (openni) after copying it to a new directory, and the failures were due to the old path being cached somehow, even when using rosmake --pre-clean. The solution seems to have been to do 'make wipe' in the affected packages. Is there something like rosmake --wipe? Was there a better way to do this?

(edit: question title was originally "Should I always use rosmake or can I use make sometimes?" but I went on a bit of a tangent in the body. The new title is a bit better I think.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9115/cleaning-up-when-moving-a-stack/package-to-a-different-directory-so-rosmake-won%27t-complain/) by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2264 on 2011-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you want:

find -name CMakeCache.txt -delete

I'm guessing it is the cmake generated makefiles that are problematic (they don't like being moved around).  The missing CMakeCache.txt will force regeneration.

---

Originally posted by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) with karma: 426 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure how to answer this as the title is different from the background...

You don't need to always use rosmake.  rosmake is just there to help you build your package's dependencies.  I find myself typing make much more often than rosmake as it is much, much faster if you are just making a local modification that you need to test.

This may change in the future as we bring rosmake and the 'make' level build system closer together, but, for now, that's my answer.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-17**:
This is really is a problem with the openni Makefiles in that the clean should be enough but isn't.

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-02-17**:
So another way to put it (and maybe I should make this a new question): what is the best command to use to clear out all of the stuff that is generated by rosmake, in particular, the stuff that causes rosmake to barf if you move the directory?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-02-17**:
'wipe' is currently not a builtin target of rosmake.  There is the custom --target command, but that isn't quite the same.

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-02-17**:
Sorry if the question was a bit confusing. What I was getting at was that, there seemed to be something I could do (make wipe) only with make and not with rosmake--making me wonder if maybe it could be done with rosmake and I just couldn't see how.